# can we have dynamic application icon & splash screen for iPhone OS 4.0/3.0?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I can make the splash screen dynamic... but wat about the icon ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't think this can be done as your app icon cannot be changed once the app is bundled and stored on the device.

Of course you can ask for a badge to be added to your app icon when it's shown on the home screen; like Mail app.